# Check if a value exists in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which consists of 3000 latitude longitude values. I want to check if a lat-long exists in the dataframe or not.

The data frame looks like the following:

```
lat      long
31.76    77.84
31.77    77.84
31.78    77.84
32.76    77.85
```

Now, I want to check if (31.76, 77.84) exists or not in the above dataframe. If yes, then the index also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with `float`s, so need [`numpy.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) for check both columns, chain with `&` for bitwise `AND` and test with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html) for at least one `True` of boolean mask:

```
tup = (31.76, 77.84)
lat, long = tup

a = (np.isclose(df['lat'], lat) & np.isclose(df['long'], long)).any()
print (a)
True
```

Comment: Thanks, and how can I know the index number of that lat-long in the dataframe?

Comment: @lsr729 - Use `out = df.index[(np.isclose(df['lat'], lat) & np.isclose(df['long'], long))]`